# unix command to redirects output to a file

Tags: unix

I am trying to write a unix command which will write/redirects the output to a file i.e. create a file if there is difference in 2 files else it will not create the file.

I am using the below command but it always creates a file(of 0B if no diff), no matter there is any difference in file or not.

```
diff -u -w a.txt b.txt > diff.tmp
```

I am trying to write a single unix command that will create file "diff.tmp" if "a.txt" is not equal to "b.txt" else "diff.tmp" will not be created.

Thanks in advance,
Pritish

Comment: You'll either have to remove the file later, in case it's empty; or test the matching between files "a.txt" and "b.txt" prior to redirecting anything to "diff.txt."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash you could remove it afterwards:

```
diff -u -w a.txt b.txt > diff.tmp && if [ -f diff.tmp ] && [ ! -s diff.tmp ]; then rm diff.tmp; fi
```

Note:

- `-f`: to check if the file exits (`-e` to check if a file, directory, etc. exists)
- `-s`: to check if the file is non-zero

Answer (score 1):

However  can will work for text files ..you can use cmp command as well.

```
cmp a.txt b.txt > cmp.tmp && if [ -f cmp.tmp ] && [ ! -s cmp.tmp ]; then rm cmp.tmp; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check return code of diff. From man page:

```
Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.
```

So I would write something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
diff "$1" "$2" 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then 
echo "No diff found!"
else 
echo "Diff saved in file "$3
diff $1 $2 > $3
fi
```

And then you call it like

```
./diff.sh a.txt b.txt diff.tmp
```

Hope it helps!

Bye
Piero